# information about drag & drop!

Tags: windows

presently I am doing a program for audio player in HTML & javascript.I want to DRag some songs from my files and drop to my audio player program.plesse ,how can i?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jQuery UI library](https://web.archive.org/web/20130512040912/http://docs.jquery.com/UI/) to do the heavy lifting, otherwise it'll be a world of pain to get right, and to make it work it all the common browsers.

There's an article on how to do that here: [Using JQuery to Add Drag and Drop Support](https://web.archive.org/web/20210210233758/http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/02/21/119882.aspx)

Comment: I thought the requirement is to drag and drop a file from the disk to the browser.

Comment: Ah... I thought it was more like building a playlist within the application, but now that I read it again, you're probably right. @jafar, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a drag and drop applet probably. There are a lot of free drag and drop applets available in the Internet which are easy to configure and use. (Interestingly Google is not working for me right now. Let me look at it :)